# Formato de Data (DataAnnotations) não funciona - Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, dataannotations

Estou tendo problemas com a exibição de um formato de datetime. Eu recebo do "12/03/1980 12:34:09", mas só aparece a máscara de entrada. Como fazer a data ser exibida juntamente com a hora?

Obrigado :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
[DisplayName("Data/Hora de Inclusao")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Data em formato inválido")]
public DateTime DataHoraInclusao { get; set; }
```

Comment: tira esse `DisplayFormat`? e me fala

Comment: Removi, só que a data é exibida assim: 12/03/1980 12:34:09,864

Comment: É o formato no DisplayFormat que você colocou errado tá vendo coloque do jeito que está ai dia, mês, ano horas minutos e segundos dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss teste?

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado :)